# File Handling in C reading multiple chars

Tags: c++, c

> ```
> abort action                        islemi durdur(MS)
> abort sequence                      durdurma dizisi(IBM)
> ```

I have a file.txt like above. I want to read this from the file.txt separately. Besides the file.txt I got 2 more turkce.txt and ingilizce.txt

Here is what I want to do :

I want to read from file.txt and separate the words English and Turkish. After that ingilizce.txt become like this

> abort action
>   abort sequence

and turkce.txt like this

> islemi durdur(MS)
>   durdurma dizisi(IBM)

Also, I have multiple columns and 5127 rows. Column numbers can changes each and every row.

Here is a pic of some part of my file.txt 
http://i59.tinypic.com/33m0iu8.png

Thank you for your answers.

Update : I solved the problem. The difference between left column's starting of first letter and right column's starting of firs letter are same and it equals 37.

So I use

```
FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
char s[256];
fgets(s, 37 , "fp);
```

Comment: C != C++, and have you tried anything yet (we are not going to just write code for you)?

Comment: Does the Turkish part start at the same column, e.g. column 36, in each line? Are there only spaces between the English and Turkish parts? Or may there be tabs? Or are these two parts even separated by tabs? You should be more specific.

Comment: It changes each and every row. I have got 5127 different row. @crashmstr   I'm not waiting for you to write code for me. I just need idea about how to do that.

Comment: In that case, I'd read the file line by line and look for stretches of two or more white-space characters and interpret them as separator. This should work if your vocabulary entries never have more than one space between words.

Comment: Well, judging from the picture, the Turkish parts always starts in the same column for every line. (Of corse, the lines themselves are different.) Apart from not showing any code, you should at least make an effort to describe your problem precisely.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried fscanf and fgets functions but these functions read line by line. In this case I need read coulumn by coulumn. Everyone knows about fscanf or fgets functions about how to use them. That is why I didn't show any code blocks at my post. And also I don't need any specific code for it. You are not my employees but at least you can suggest your ideas for the solution. I need your ideas ,suggestion or advice not your codes. It called brainstorm , remember ?

Comment: There has to be one or more questions already asked about reading text files.  Try searching for "stackoverflow c++ read file struct" or "stackoverflow c++ read file columns".

Comment: @MustafaAlp it doesn't seem like you're looking to understand the problem, overcome difficulty in particular part of attempted solution or anything like this. Especially when You take someones code and try to use it to no avail, only to comment that it's not working. It seems you're looking for a working specific solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say it explicitly, but your file has two fixed-width columns, which you want to separate.

A substring of a string `str` from a fixed index `i` to the end can be expressed with pointer arithmetic: `str + i` or `&str[i]`. Strings that are not zero-terminated (like your first column) can be printed by specifying a length with `printf`s precision field, e.g. `printf("%.*s", len, str)`.

A quick and dirty way to print your two columns is:

```
char line[80];
int col = 36;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in)) {
    fprintf(en, "%.*s\n", col, line);
    fprintf(tr, "%s", line + col);
    printf("\n");
}
```

This method has some drawbacks: It will print garbage if the string is shorter than your separation width, i.e. if the right column is empty. It also prints the column padding spaces for the left column, which looks untidy. So let's write a function that splits the strings nicely, which we can call like so:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in)) {
    char *stren, *strtr;

    split_at(line, &stren, &strtr, 36);

    fprintf(en, "%s\n", stren);
    fprintf(tr, "%s\n", strtr);
}
```

The function looks like this:

```
void split_at(char *line, char **left, char **right, int col)
{
    char *trim = line;
    char *p = line;

    *left = line;
    *right = line + col;

    while (p < *right) {
        if (*p == '\0') {
            *right = p;
            break;
        }

        if (!isspace(*p)) trim = p + 1;
        p++;
    }

    *trim = '\0';
    trim = p;

    while (*p) {
        if (!isspace(*p)) trim = p + 1;        
        p++;
    }

    if (trim) *trim = '\0';
}
```

This should work for your example data. It will also work for empty left or right columns. It will not work if there is no space between the left and right columns, i.e. when the left and right art are pasted together.

This method will also work only if the code points of the strings have the same length. You haven't said which encoding you use for your data. If you use ISO-8859-9, you will be okay. If you use UTF-8, all non ASCII-codepoints, i.e. the Turkish special characters, will be represented by more than one byte. What looks like a fixed-width column doesn't have a fixed width in its memory representation.

That said, you should be safe as long as your English text is in the left column. English text is made up of only ASCII characters unless you have fancy formatting with typographic quotation marks or some such.

Answer (score 0):

There could be better solutions but here is simple one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream inFile("file.txt");
  std::ofstream outFileT("turkce.txt", std::ios::app);
  std::ofstream outFileE("ingilizce.txt", std::ios::app);
  std::string a;
  std::string b;

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    inFile >> a >> b;
    outFileE << a + " " + b + "\n";

    inFile >> a >> b;
    outFileT << a + " " + b + "\n";
 }
}
```

I assumed you have two lines but you can determine lines count in the file first.

Comment: This code will work for the shown input file excerpt, where both English and Turkish parts have two words each, but for not much else. What about determining the end of input by an end-of-file condition?

Comment: @MustafaAlp You need to have file.txt file in directory where executable runs. In the same directory will be created two files turkce.txt ingilizce.txt. Did you get error?

Comment: No , I didn't get the any error the code above. But I have multiple coulumns not just 2.